# How do I find what value to pass to uncheck a checkbox?

Tags: python, post

How do I pass a url and uncheck a checkbox in a post request.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="encodeURL" ID="encodeURL" checked="checked">
```

I am using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), a 3rd party python library, like so:

```
payload = {'u': 'http://www.google.com', 'encodeURL': '0'}
r = requests.post('http://www.website.com/', data=payload)
```

So far setting 'encodeURL' to '0', 'unchecked', '' and 0 is NOT posting the request with the checkbox unchecked.
How do I find what value to pass to 'encodeURL' in order to uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: I'm not really sure what 3rd party library you're using, or what to do with it, but in terms of HTML, taking out `checked="checked"` will generate an unchecked box.

Comment: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) I'm using this python library.

Comment: I have to set encodeURL to something other than 'checked' since it is checked by default.

Comment: encodeURL isn't making the checkbox checked, the "checked" attribute is

Comment: @jedwards I have also passed checked as checked=""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SUMMARY - TL/DR**

To uncheck a box - **exclude** it in the payload

```
payload = {'u': 'http://www.google.com'}
r = requests.post('http://www.website.com/', data=payload)
```

To check a box - **include** it in the payload

```
payload = {'u': 'http://www.google.com', 'allowCookies': 'on'}
r = requests.post('http://www.website.com/', data=payload)
```

**EXPLANATION**

One needs to distinguish html markup (where the checkbox is set by default in your example) from the server-side behaviour, which is completely orthogonal. What you apparently want to do, is to mimic the behaviour of a browser when you submit the form with the unchecked checkbox.
In this case, the server would not receive *any* `encodeURL` parameter whatsoever, just omit it from the request.

See also the [HTML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#checkbox)

> When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become [successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).

**UPDATE**

After investigating your particular case with TamperData plugin, I figured out that it might have to do with how speed-limit handles cookies, so that's not a requests library's bug, just a site peculiarity. This code seems to work:

```
s = requests.session()
s.get('http://speed-limit.info/index.php')  # getting the cookies
response = s.post('http://speed-limit.info/includes/process.php?action=update', 
                  data={'u': 'stackoverflow.com', 'allowCookies': 'on'},
                  allow_redirects=True)
```

Then the `encodeURL` in the response is unchecked (I hope, that's what you meant).

Comment: Ok, after reading your links I understand I can't set encodeURL to anything. If I omit it from the request, it'll still be checked, since it is checked by default.

Comment: @DaveCastillo "It'll still be checked" - checked where? Provide the full data flow of your request (preferrably, with the server-side code).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is pass a url and uncheck EncryptURL on the site [speed-limit](http://speed-limit.info). The reason why I was trying to set encodeURL to '0' is because when I pass a url to 'u', e.g. `<input type="text" name="u"> it successfully makes a post request with my url as a variable.

Comment: @DaveCastillo Ok, I see. Once again, the fact that the checkbox is checked by default in the markup has nothing whatsoever to do with the request you need to send. Server-side logic is not aware about checkboxes etc, it works in terms of query parameters. Omitting `encodeURL` from the request is exactly what a browser does when you uncheck it.

Comment: @DaveCastillo I made some extra research and updated the answer (hope, it helps).

Comment: @ bereal Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was trying todo. One tiny little thing, it is actually `allow_redirects=True`, there is an 's' in the end.

Comment: @DaveCastillo yep, fixed that.

Answer (score -1):

// Check

```
document.getElementById("encodeURL").checked = true;
```

//  Uncheck

```
document.getElementById("encodeURL").checked = false;
```

jQuery (1.6+):

// Check

```
$("#encodeURL").prop("checked", true);
```

//  Uncheck

```
$("#encodeURL").prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: The question was about Python (well, not exactly, but this does not answer anyway)